# From WPF to Android App - Send one String and Picture to all devices

Tags: android, wpf

I am absolutely new in Android and I only would appreciate some tips on which tools to use for my goal, because I d not have the experience which would fit best.

- I wrote an WPF Application in C# for managing events!
- I wrote an Android App for representing planned Events to the User (at the moment 
  always only one --> the next)

**My Goal is:**

- Feed all Android Devices which have the App istalled with a String (One or two
  sentences including date, time, location,..) and one picture. This is managed  out of 
  the WPF Application on local desktop computer.

**C#:** Creating an Event object in each needed form is possible. --> Working all fine

**App:** I created one Layout with an TextView and ImageView --> Working all fine

So my question(s):

- Should I use Google app Engine Datastore to have always only one Entity of an Event in 
  the store, which is uploaded via my WPF Application. Android App are
  loading the event each time the Layout/Activity is started.
- Should I use Google Cloud Messaging to send the String Message and App Engine to 
  provide the picture?

So, I am not looking for Code, just for help about the strategy to achieve my Goal!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: for the Android devices, use GCM to push the string and the url to download the image. if the image is small enough, you could probably do something like Base64 encode it and put it in the push, but it's better to have the app go get it.

Comment: Hi, thanx for fast reply! So with "url" u mean the locator for my app in App Engine if understand right?

Comment: i mean the url to the image. something like `http://your.server.com/images/image.png`. then the app can download the image.

Comment: i am a poor man and i dont have a own webserver running 24 hours a day. so i am addicted to services like app engine or something like that. but anyway, i can store the picture there, this will be no problem i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible high level solution.

Your Android client should check for new events/pictures when relevant Activities are displayed to end users (this is important because typical push notifications make no guarantees about delivery).

You can also use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) to notify devices that an update has occurred. However, attempting to sending an image from a GCM message is probably a bad idea.  Instead, when a device receives a notification, it should contain the URL of the image, which the device can then download itself.

Also note that not all devices will work with GCM. A requirement for using GCM is a valid Google account on a device, which may or may not be present. Additionally, GCM requires you to add several permissions to your manifest (which some users may not be happy about).

Comment: Hi, thanks too! So this menas heading App Engine App an device polling? As mentioned above, I do not own a web server, so I have to use Data Store of App Engine or something like that. (or maybe Drop Box or whatever). But u are right, I did not think about the permissions and about guaranted delivery due to a message. Google Account is not a problem I think, because Android wont work without, isnt it!?

Comment: The general architecture in all cases would involve a web server that devices will request information from (i.e. events and images). Also, in the case of GCM, you'll need to do a lot of server-side bookkeeping with device IDs when you send out messages.

Comment: I understand, ... therefore I think I will use the "free" services of the Google App Engine. WPF:
- Set online = Store it in the Web Data Store
- Set it offline = Delete it from the store an host a Dummy
  or store a new event/picture (The entities allow all kind of data)

- Devices: Check new data each time the activity is started (not so difficult because of good Google Apis therefore)